# InvocationList of event is wrong

Tags: c#, events

I have a weird problem setting and removing events. Unfortunately my problem is very complex and it's not possible to demonstrate it here with a simple example.
Therefore I will draw my problem schematically and hopefully someone will have an idea.

I have a class that contains a collection of objects MyObject

```
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyObject>
{
}
```

Additionally I have a class MyObjectView to view each MyObject in a grid.
I attach to the CollectionChanged of MyCollection and create a MyObjectView  for each MyObject and add the MyObjectView to the grid. The MyObjectView also registers for the CollectionChanged from MyCollection.

Any time the MyCollection changes all MyObjectView are deleted and unregistered from the CollectionChanged.

So here's an example:
1. I add a new MyObject, then a new MyObjectView 1 is created and added to the grid.
2. I add a new MyObject, then the old MyObjectView 1 is destroyed, unregistered and removed from the grid.
3. Now two new MyObjectViews 2+3 are created, registered to CollectionChanged from MyCollection and added to the grid.

Unregistering from the CollectionChanged event works fine and I can see that only
MyObjectView 2+3 is in the InvocationList. MyObjectView 1 is not in the list.

If now an CollectionChanged event is raised, suddenly also MyObjectView 1 gets the event. I have tried to check what's going on in that I created my own add/remove handlers to a list in the event. The list also looks good. It contains the contents I assume. But when I call ToArray() or CopyTo and get a completely different content. I get the first content and not the current content.

So the event contains MyObjectView 2+3 when looking in the list. When looking in the array which is returned by ToArray(), I get MyObjectView 1.

```
List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> aHandlers = new List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();

public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
{ 
add {aHandlers.Add(value);}
remove {aHandlers.Remove(value);}
}

public void RaiseChangedEvent()
{
// here's the problem aHandlers has 2 items, where handlers only has 1
NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler[] handlers = aHandlers.ToArray();

foreach  (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler aHandler in handlers )
{
aHandler(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionAction.Reset));  
}
}
```

There is no threading, and everything happens in the same thread. I don't really know what the problem could be.

Comment: You need to show us your code. It sounds like you are making a copy or your delegate before detaching, but I can't tell unless I see your code.

Comment: Enigmativity: Thank for the reply. I added a piece to show what's going on. This is not completely. Your answer was what I was also thinking of, but I couldn't find where. I will dig a little more and show some examples.

Comment: You're writing some odd code for dealing with events. Why use a list of handlers? Now, by doing `aHandlers.ToArray();` you're copying the handlers, but in the code you've shown you're only invoking them. You need to provide a [mcve].